# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'TextToSpeech.speak')

Tags: android, react-native

I am using react-native-tts for text to speech and its working properly but when include react-native-voice for speech to text .it starts showing error on react-native-tts.it shows following error.

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'TextToSpeech.speak')
```

however both modules works fine when used seperately

Comment: Can you paste your code here where you are using both? I don't have enough information to help you without understanding your use-case and to decide if this is a bug. Please, feel free to open an issue on the repository [wenkesj/react-native-voice](https://github.com/wenkesj/react-native-voice). Also, please make sure you have linked BOTH libraries to your current project, manually or automatically with `react-native link`.